# How can "to have no illusions that something will happen" mean to be convinced/aware that something will happen?

Tags: expressions

I read the following sentence in a book:

> The U.S basketball team have no illusions that they can beat Lithuania.

Given that the U.S would have been red hot favourites for this game I found this sentence peculiar to say the least.

For me, the "illusion" is qualified by "that they can beat". To not have that illusion would suggest that they don't believe they could beat Lithuania.

Someone told me that "no illusion" must mean to be convinced or very aware but I do not understand how it could mean that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: "having no illusion" about something to occur is to be convinced that the event won't happen. In the mentionned context, Lithuanians may have no illusions that they will win.

Comment: I would share your puzzlement over this usage. Often in sport reporting, red-hot favourites like to play down the fact, and not belittle the weaker opposition.  They will assert that the game/match still has to be won, with something like" We have no illusions about this being an easy game, and Lithuania will be tough.", or something similar. So I suspect the sample sentence is a case of the writer getting the standard phrase wrong.

Comment: Where did you find this sentence? Which book? Google can't seem to  find "no illusions that they can beat Lithuania", but I did find (in a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Other_Dream_Team)): _The Lithuanian team had no illusions of beating the American Dream Team in the semifinals_.

Comment: @StoneyB A quick Google search shows that you seem to be correct so I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 3):

"The U.S basketball team have no illusions that they can beat Lithuania" means that U.S. team is rightly convinced that it cannot beat Lithuania. This seems like it must be a typographical error, because, yes, the U.S. team (i.e., a team of major college and/or professional players, as in the Olympics) would certainly be favored over Lithuania. Be that as it may, the opposite would be "The U.S. team has the illusion that it can beat Lithuania," meaning that the U.S. team believes it can win, but that the speaker believes this is an impossibility. In both cases, the speaker is convinced the U.S. cannot win--perhaps the speaker is a Lithuanian? In your sentence, the U.S. agrees with this assessment--it cannot win; in the opposite, the U.S. disagrees with the idea that it cannot win, but the speaker remains convinced that it cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon the phrase "have no illusions that" should be interpreted as "have no doubt that (=believe that)". As an example of this usage, I wll cite a quotation from "The Day of the Jackal" by Frederick Forsyth below.

A lean and fanatical colonel in Rome had devised a plan that could still bring the whole edifice tumbling down by organising the death of a single man. Some countries have institutions of sufficient stability to survive the death of a president or the abdication of a king, as Britain had shown twenty-eight years earlier and America would show before the year was out. But Roger Frey was well enough aware of the state of the institutions of France in 1963 to have no illusions that the death of his President could only be the prologue to putsch and civil war.